# How to loop through child records in firebase?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to figure out how to loop through sent_request child which is inside users table and get all user_keys. I tried many ways but it's not working.

**table structure:**

[image: database structure]

**here is my code:**

```
getProfileData(emailID)
{
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('users');
    ref.orderByChild("email").equalTo(emailID).once("value", (items : any) => {
        let sent_request : any = [];

        items.forEach((item) => {

            sent_request = item.val().sent_request;

        });
        console.log(sent_request);
    });
}
```

**console.log(sent_request) output:**

[image: output]

How to get user_key from these records? because I want to pass these each user_key to another method and get records based on that user_key.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code looks fine on first glance. What isn't working about it? Does it ever get to your callback? Are there any relevant errors on the console?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen There are no errors. my question is how to get each user_key which are inside sent_request child inside users table?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for this:

```
ref.orderByChild("email").equalTo(emailID).once("value", (usersSnapshot : any) => {
    let sent_request : any = [];

    usersSnapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) => {

        userSnapshot.child("send_request").forEach((requestSnapshot) => {
            sent_request.push(requestSnapshot.key);
            // OR: sent_request.push(requestSnapshot.child("user"key").val());

        }

    });
    console.log(sent_request);
});
```